# How would I go about simulating conditional random birth 100 times?

Tags: code-review, simulation, code-request

So I have the following scenario:

Assume you have this organism that reproduces by itself. An organism either reproduces 0, 1, 2, or 3 organisms at a time. Assume they're asexual and reproduce only in sets of event. It can create:

no offspring with probability 11/32
1 offspring with probability 3/8
2 offspring with probability 3/16
3 offspring with probability 3/32

So, for example, an organism can create 0 offspring and stop creating forever, or it can create 1 offspring and stop forever, or it can create 2 offspring at once and stop forever, or it can create 3 offspring and stop forever.

How would I simulate 6 generations 100 times and find the average? I'm confused on the syntax. I feel like there's a lot of lists, tables, etc. to juggle and things to define.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
    X:=RandomReal[]
    (*define some counter variable*)
    (*Assume I start off with 1 person, so counter=1*)
    (*If X<=11/32, counter=counter, 11/32<X<=3/8, counter=counter+1, etc.*)
    (*That's generation 1)
    (*generation 2 has new counter individuals, and I repeat the process until 6 generations, potentially do something like (for i = 1 to counter, do the if X rules again*)

    Then stick on a bigger for loop from j = 1 to 100 at the top, print it, put it in a table, and average the table?
```

Does this sound reasonable? Can someone help me put this code to fruition? Also, does anyone know of a more efficient process?

Comment: This problem lends itself to recursion, which you really should master in order to get the most out of *Mathematica*. It is also a good idea to tell yourself to avoid for loops as much as possible, you have one in your algorithm - from that alone I could tell that that's not how experienced Mathematica users would implement this, before I even knew the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
nextGen[n_] := Total@RandomChoice[{11/32, 3/8, 3/16, 3/32} -> {0, 1, 2, 3}, n]
simulate[n0_, nrOfGenerations_] := Total@NestList[nextGen, n0, nrOfGenerations]
```

Now we can simulate six generations a hundred times and compute the mean value. The initial number of organisms is 10 in this example.

```
Table[simulate[10, 6], {100}] // Mean // N
(* Out: 75.42 *)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the existing population at each iteration (unless the OP means one-shot at reproduction per new generation).

Comment: @rasher The OP explicitly says that each generation can only reproduce one time ("...and stop creating forever.")